# How to change color of column in table

Tags: tables, color

I am using this code for a table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{Thesis}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|C{5cm}|C{5cm}|C{5cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} \\ 
\hline
 & Means of Mounting & Material & Means of De-mounting \\ \hline   
1 & Friction & Rubber & Lever \\ \hline
2 & Tight Fit(Formschluss) & Magnet & Complete Removal \\ \hline
3 & Holes & Alloy & Spring/Elasticity \\ \hline

\end{tabular}}
\caption{Morphological Box}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I want to color the background of each column

Comment: Unrelated, but `usenames` option for `xcolor` shouldn't be used any more: it's the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{Thesis}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{ |>{\columncolor{red!30}}c|
                  >{\columncolor{blue!30}}p{5cm}|
                  >{\columncolor{yellow!30}}p{5cm}|
                  >{\columncolor{green!30}}p{5cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} \\
\hline
 & Means of Mounting & Material & Means of De-mounting \\ \hline
1 & Friction & Rubber & Lever \\ \hline
2 & Tight Fit(Formschluss) & Magnet & Complete Removal \\ \hline
3 & Holes & Alloy & Spring/Elasticity \\ \hline

\end{tabular}}
\caption{Morphological Box}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Details how to color tables you can find in documentation of package `colortbl` (which is called and extended by option `table` when loading `xcolor`).

In your MWE you not define column type `C{...}`, so I use `p{...}`. Also your table is wider then text width.

Answer (score 0):

use the package "`colortbl`" and the tag is `cellcolor`, `rowcolor` and `columncolor`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{Thesis}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} \\ 
\hline\rowcolor{cyan!10}
 & Means of Mounting & Material & Means of De-mounting \\ \hline   
1 & \cellcolor{cyan!20}Friction & Rubber & Lever \\ \hline
2 & Tight Fit(Formschluss) & Magnet & Complete Removal \\ \hline
3 & \multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{cyan!20}}c}{Holes} & Alloy & Spring/Elasticity \\ \hline

\end{tabular}}
\caption{Morphological Box}

\end{table}
```

Comment: I changed it to the following and it still doesnt work, please suggest the changes.

    \begin{tabular}{ |c \columncolor{red}|C{5cm}|C{5cm}|C{5cm}|}

Comment: I have edited my answer with all three samples...